# Pictures directory suddenly 'unable to find'

Tags: files, data-recovery, directory

[image: Popup]

This morning I went to save an image and although my Pictures directory can be seen, when I click on it, I get the message that the file/directory cannot  be found and my 1000's of photos have disappeared. The Trash is also empty.

[image: Directory list]

output of `ls -Al ~ ~/.dropbox-dist`:

```
gary@gary-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-2nd:~$ ls -Al ~ ~/.dropbox-dist
/home/gary:
total 816261
drwxrwxr-x 15 gary gary      4096 May  7  2017 1-Gary
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  45274341 Apr 24  2016 1 HOUR Romantic Piano Music _ Latest Rexation Music 2016-NgBdG8VgDRM.mp3
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 18  2016 .adobe
drwxr-x---  2 gary gary      4096 Feb  7  2017 .android
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3546453 Nov 20 00:21 Anne-Marie & James Arthur - Rewrite The Stars [from The Greatest Showman - Reimagined]-pRfmrE0ToTo.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary       114 Nov 12  2017 .apport-ignore.xml
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Mar 21 14:28 .aptitude
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary     52278 Oct 30 11:34 asia_2016.odt
drwxrwxr-x  4 gary gary      4096 Sep 26 08:24 .audacity-data
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3432885 Nov 18 10:12 Ava Max - Sweet but Psycho [Official Music Video]-WXBHCQYxwr0.mp3
-rw-------  1 gary gary    144827 Mar 21 12:15 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 gary gary       220 Nov 13  2016 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 gary gary      4167 May  2  2018 .bashrc
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary      3771 May  2  2018 .bashrc_bacxkup
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary 143800005 Oct 26 06:20 Best of Shingo Nakamura 01 (2-Hour Melodic Progressive House Mix)-WYp9Eo9T3BA.mp3
drwxrwxr--  6 gary gary      4096 Jul 28  2017 .BitwigStudio
drwxrwxr-x  6 gary gary      4096 Jul 27  2017 Bitwig Studio
drwx------ 32 gary gary      4096 Mar  7 15:24 .cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   4548453 Sep 19  2018 C+C Music Factory - Gonna Make You Sweat (Everybody Dance Now) ft. Freedom Williams-LaTGrV58wec.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   4122033 Feb  2 13:39 Chaka Khan - Like Sugar (Official Video)-RecY5iZn6B0.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   4038370 Oct 23 01:07 Charles J - Do You Want (Original Mix)-_q2m_8fol2U.mp3
drwxr-xr-x  5 gary gary      4096 Oct 20 20:30 Charts
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  44453932 Jan 25  2018 (Christina Perri) A Thousand Years - Sungha Jung-VKEq8HFDKwU.webm
drwxrwxr-x  6 gary gary      4096 Sep 12  2017 .clamtk
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3959349 Nov  5 23:50 Clean Bandit - Baby (feat. Marina & Luis Fonsi) [Official Video]-hlznpxNGFGQ.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   4299405 Feb 26 21:39 Clean Bandit - Mama (feat. Ellie Goulding) [Official Video]-Ao3XJ-UDdzI.mp3
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 22  2016 .compiz
drwx------ 53 gary gary      4096 Mar 21 14:28 .config
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Nov 19  2016 .cups
drwx------  3 root root      4096 Aug 31  2017 .dbus
drwxr-xr-x  5 gary gary      4096 Jan 22 19:34 Desktop
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  25906711 Apr  1  2015 DIY Solar Ice Maker - solar powered 'off grid' ice maker - easy to set up! - use HFT panels-T9CcPZMK-bc.mp4
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3735357 Dec  7 19:35 DJ Snake - Taki Taki ft. Selena Gomez, Ozuna, Cardi B-ixkoVwKQaJg.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3414885 Dec 13 00:10 DJ YANKEE X DICE AILES - LEAN ON ME-Oeya0lh9NY0.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 gary gary        25 Nov 13  2016 .dmrc
drwxr-xr-x  5 gary gary     12288 Mar 21 14:36 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 23 gary gary     16384 Mar 20 14:11 Downloads
drwx------  7 gary gary      4096 Mar 21 14:22 .dropbox
drwx------ 22 gary gary      4096 Oct 19 01:05 Dropbox
drwxr-xr-x  3 gary gary      4096 Mar 20 02:34 .dropbox-dist
drwxr-xr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Dec 19  2016 dwhelper
drwxrwxrwx 27 gary gary      4096 Nov 16 01:00 E Books
-rw-r--r--  1 gary gary      8980 Nov 13  2016 examples.desktop
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Mar 14 21:48 .FBReader
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3326749 Feb 13 09:03 Filatov & Karas - Au Au (Official Music Video) [Premiere]-06aGC9gqy1I.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary         0 Nov  8 01:50 foo2zjs.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3064557 Oct 26 06:29 Freya Ridings - Lost Without You (Official Video)-tDPpex1wvOc.mp3
drwx------  4 gary gary      4096 Mar 21 14:22 .gconf
drwxr--r-- 18 gary gary      4096 Feb 17 10:53 gdalwmscache
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3037701 Nov  5 15:04 George Ezra - Hold My Girl (Official Video)-6Xlo2abddXU.mp3
drwxr-xr-x 24 gary gary      4096 Mar 19 13:37 .gimp-2.8
-rw-r-----  1 gary gary         0 Feb 16 21:27 .gksu.lock
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 18  2016 .gnome
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Sep 30  2017 .gnome2
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Aug 27  2017 .gnome2_private
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Mar 21 14:22 .gnupg
drwx------  5 gary gary      4096 Mar 17  2018 .googleearth
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  57842874 Aug 19  2017 google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  57842874 Aug 19  2017 google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb.1
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Nov 18  2016 .gphoto
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Mar 13 14:33 .grsync
drwx------  2 root root      4096 Aug 31  2017 .gvfs
drwxrwxrwx 10 gary gary      4096 Nov 11 05:17 Health&Exercise
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  14469661 Jun  4  2017 HouseLogix - HDMI Repair Kit Installation-IrNk85K4Zbo.webm
drwxr-xr-x  3 gary gary      4096 Mar 21 14:22 .hplip
-rw-------  1 gary gary    344436 Mar 21 14:22 .ICEauthority
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   5303541 Oct 28 22:46 JABBAWOCKEEZ x Tiësto - BOOM with Gucci Mane & Sevenn-QYU18mrBB54.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3081669 Nov 28 18:53 Jax Jones, Years & Years - Play (Visualiser)-HuIrr-qJ_UQ.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3417189 Oct 20 19:22 Jess Glynne - Thursday [Official Audio]-D-F9h6lu7fQ.mp3
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Feb 14 09:41 .john
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3356045 Jan 12 02:57 KARA MARNI - Love Just Ain't Enough (Official Video)-73hvZ77fzFM.mp3
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov  4 00:19 .kde
drwxrwxr-x  6 gary gary      4096 May 10  2017 kdenlive
drwxr-xr-x  4 gary gary      4096 Feb 25  2017 .lastpass
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 13  2016 .local
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   5141581 Oct  3  2015 Los del Rio - Macarena (DJ Dero Latin Piano Remix)-QqoBwPstEPk.mp3
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary     44708 Oct 20  2014 lsb-core_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary     20330 Oct 20  2014 lsb-invalid-mta_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary     19968 Oct 20  2014 lsb-security_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_amd64.deb
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 18  2016 .macromedia
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary       254 Sep  3  2017 Mama's Guesthouse & Restaurant.desktop
drwxrwxr-x  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 14 21:32 .masterpdfeditor
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  10525544 Sep  8  2017 master-pdf-editor.deb
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   4173132 Oct 29 01:02 MC Hammer - U Can't Touch This-otCpCn0l4Wo.mp3
drwxrwxr-x  3 gary gary      4096 Jan 16  2018 media
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3187725 Dec 10 13:31 Meek Mill - Going Bad feat. Drake [Official Audio]-T3lKEb0Cs94.mp3
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 May  6  2017 Movies
drwx------  5 gary gary      4096 Nov 18  2017 .mozilla
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary    186033 Mar  9  2017 mozilla.pdf
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Nov  4 07:11 mpd-configure
drwxr-xr-x  8 gary gary      4096 Nov  7 23:30 Music
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Nov  1 00:30 .nano
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Mar 20 14:16 .opencpn
drwxr-x---  6 gary gary      4096 May 10  2017 .openshot
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov  1 01:25 openvpn-ca
-rwxrwxr-x  1 gary gary     36406 Nov  1 19:11 openvpn-install.sh
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Jul 27  2017 .oracle_jre_usage
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary 244043475 Jan 11 13:11 Our annual Kingston drone montage is here!  We made this for you fellow Kings...-543481986168357.mp4
drwxr-xr-x  4 gary gary      4096 Mar 21 12:16 .pcloud
drwxr-xr-x  7 gary gary      4096 Nov  1 06:31 pCloudDrive
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3590511 Mar 19 10:39 Pink Panda   Love It Like That feat  Nyanda (Extended Mix) By Michael Sharre-juawBq4gdkQ.mp3
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 18  2016 .pki
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   2667261 Oct 27 23:20 P!nk & Willow Sage Hart (P!nk’s Daughter) - A Million Dreams_A Million Dreams (Reprise)-V1weVGUmNTA.mp3
-rw-r--r--  1 gary gary       655 Nov 13  2016 .profile
drwxrwxr-x  3 gary gary      4096 Mar 15  2017 projects
drwxr-xr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Nov 13  2016 Public
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Jul 29  2017 .putty
drwxrwxr-x  8 gary gary      4096 Feb 17 10:53 .qgis2
drwxr-xr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Dec  3 21:40 Recordings
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary      1088 Feb 14  2017 Release.key
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Nov 19 00:26 .remmina
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary      1516 Sep  9  2017 .ripperXrc
-rw-------  1 gary gary      1024 Nov  1 00:48 .rnd
drwxr-xr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Nov  2 08:07 .rpmdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary   3863109 Oct 28 19:07 RUN-DMC, Jason Nevins - It's Like That (Video)-TLGWQfK-6DY.mp3
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Nov  4 04:48 sambashare
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 19  2016 .sane
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary        98 Apr  7  2017 .scdl.cfg
drwx------  6 gary gary      4096 Dec 10  2017 .Skype
drwxr-xr-x  8 gary gary      4096 Dec  2 19:48 snap
drwxr-xr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Sep 13  2017 sophos-av
drwx------  2 gary gary      4096 Nov 22  2017 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 gary gary         0 Nov 14  2016 .sudo_as_admin_successful
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  46848618 Oct  5 17:50 teamviewer_i386.deb
drwxr-xr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Nov 13  2016 Templates
drwxrwxrwx  4 gary gary      4096 Jan  6  2016 Thai
drwx------  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 21  2016 .thumbnails
drwx------  6 gary gary      4096 Oct 18 08:41 .thunderbird
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary       242 May 16  2017 to_do_list_apr2017
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  29950518 Aug  2  2018 'Touch' composed by Mattia Cupelli-ks8UqM0MLTY.mp4
drwxrwxr-x 16 gary gary      4096 May 30  2017 TV
drwxrwxr-x  3 gary gary      4096 May  9  2018 usr
drwxrwxr-x  4 gary gary      4096 Feb  3 19:45 .ViberPC
drwxr-xr-x  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 27 03:13 Videos
-rwxrwxr-x  1 gary gary       114 Jan 14  2018 vpnbook
drwxrwxr-x  2 gary gary      4096 Jan 14  2018 VPNBook
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary        28 Jan 14  2018 vpnkill
-rw-r--r--  1 gary gary       168 Mar 16 09:19 .wget-hsts
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary  31180312 Aug  1  2017 whatsapp.deb
drwxrwxr-x  3 gary gary      4096 Nov 21  2016 Windows Programs
drwxrwxr-x  4 gary gary      4096 Mar 11 21:24 .wine
-rw-------  1 gary gary       216 Mar 21 14:22 .Xauthority
-rw-rw-r--  1 gary gary       131 Feb  4 07:28 .xinputrc
-rw-------  1 gary gary        82 Mar 21 14:22 .xsession-errors
-rw-------  1 gary gary      1256 Mar 21 14:14 .xsession-errors.old

/home/gary/.dropbox-dist:
total 20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gary gary   101 Mar 20 02:34 dropboxd
drwxr-xr-x 6 gary gary 12288 Mar 20 02:34 dropbox-lnx.x86_64-69.4.102
-rw-r--r-- 1 gary gary     8 Mar 20 02:34 VERSION
```

```
$ cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Comment: Maybe you accidentally moved the directory some place else? Is this different from your main `~/Pictures` directory?

Comment: this is my main ~/Pictures directory, and I have searched the entire drive for subdirectories and specific file names that I know were in there, and found no trace of them

Comment: There is too little information, so we can just guess… What about the `Pictures` directory just above the `Connect to Server` option? Please [edit] your post to add the output of the command `ls -Al ~ ~/.dropbox-dist`. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) for pasted terminal text. Have you checked your Dropbox history?

Comment: ok I've edited the post.. the Pictures directory is the one I get the error message when I click on it.. not sure what you mean about my Dropbox history..

Comment: Thank you for the update. Check https://help.dropbox.com/security/recover-older-versions. I am not sure whether your Pictures folder had been originally connected with Dropbox somehow – as the error dialog and the tag [tag:dropbox] you’ve used suggests. Could you add more details?

Comment: I was not aware of any connection between my Pictures folder and my Dropbox folder..  i had different collections of images in both directories..  everything in my Dropbox folder looks ok

Comment: Try `find ~ -type d -name "Pictures"` and if nothing found `sudo find / -type d -name "Pictures"`. This might take a while as it searches through all your folders. Should find your folder if you accidentally moved it somewhere else.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `~/.dropbox-dist/Pictures` is your *main `~/Pictures` directory*.

Comment: find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
find: ‘/tmp/.mount_pcloudG6WM8J’: Permission denied
/media/Data1/$UPGRADE.~OS/OnlineUpgradeStore/File/C$/Users/Public/Pictures
/media/Data1/Users/Default/Pictures
/media/Data1/Users/Gary/Pictures
/media/Data1/Users/Public/Pictures
/media/Data1/Windows/ServiceProfiles/LocalService/Pictures
/media/Data1/Windows/ServiceProfiles/NetworkService/Pictures
/home/gary/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Pictures
find: ‘/home/gary/pCloudDrive’: Permission denied

find: ‘/home/gary/pCloudDrive’: Permission denied

Comment: the Pictures folder seen in the left window was my main directory for images.. I did not say what you are asking me to clarify

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of terminal command `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`: it looks to me like you have configured your XDG `Pictures` directory to be `~/dropbox-dist/Pictures` in place of the usual `~/Pictures`

Comment: I have not seen this suggestion yet - Can ou boot from a live USB, and run `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda<number>` on your partition?

Comment: steeldriver, I added the output.. Charles Green, I did so, wasn't able to save the output but it ran without any errors

Comment: using Testdisk/PhotoRec I'm managing to recover the files, now sifting through about 150,000 recovered image files to find ones that were my photos.. will probaby never know what caused this in the first place but happy enough to be able to recover my files..  thanks again for the help!!

Comment: @djgap I’m glad you found a solution! Consider posting an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). And definitely consider backing up your important data!